# In android studio warning msg or error not showing

Tags: android

Android studio error or warning message not showing.
         I am using android studio,when coding mistake written . warning message not showing in android.here srceen shot you can see in android.

[image]

Comment: visit this link, might it help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206514/where-is-the-warnings-view-in-android-studio)

Comment: i have try this link aldready

Comment: Could you find any solution. Even I am struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Build option-> Make Project gives what we can get the equivalent of Eclipse's “Problems” view on Android Studio